# Using -fast option with Intel ICC compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, intel, icc

When I use the -fast option in the ICC compilation command under Linux,  I get this error:

```
ld: cannot find -libcm
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have the cm library installed.  Look in /usr/include to see if you have the cm/ directory or any libcm files.  If not, you're going to need to acquire it.

You can use whichever package manager your distribution has to locate it and install it.  If that doesn't work, instructions for downloading and installing it are located at
http://cblfs.cross-lfs.org/index.php/Libcm

Comment: Thanks Josh. I installed it in a local folder (I am not administrator) and added its path in the linker line: -L ~/mylib/lib but still I get the same error message!

Comment: What name do you have the library file saved as?  If your compilation script (or line or makefile or whatever you're using) is short enough, could you post it here?

Comment: I extracted libcm-0.1.1.tar.bz2 and installed it with ./configure --prefix=~/mylib &&
make and then make install, finally ~/mylib/lib indeed contains: libcm.a  libcm.la  libcm.so  libcm.so.7  libcm.so.7.0.0